# Android JSON parsing exception

Tags: php, android, json, exception, httprequest

Hello I am working on a login activity but it always displays the following error:

```
E/JSON Parser(12505): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
03-25 00:21:14.735: W/dalvikvm(12505): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41d83700)
03-25 00:21:14.775: E/AndroidRuntime(12505): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
03-25 00:21:14.775: E/AndroidRuntime(12505): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
03-25 00:21:14.775: E/AndroidRuntime(12505):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
03-25 00:21:14.775: E/AndroidRuntime(12505):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
03-25 00:21:14.775: E/AndroidRuntime(12505):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
03-25 00:21:14.775: E/AndroidRuntime(12505):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
03-25 00:21:14.775: E/AndroidRuntime(12505):    at  android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
03-25 00:21:14.775: E/AndroidRuntime(12505):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
03-25 00:21:14.775: E/AndroidRuntime(12505):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
03-25 00:21:14.775: E/AndroidRuntime(12505):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
03-25 00:21:14.775: E/AndroidRuntime(12505): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-25 00:21:14.775: E/AndroidRuntime(12505):    at com.example.maphelperlogin.Register$ProcessRegister.doInBackground(Register.java:154)
03-25 00:21:14.775: E/AndroidRuntime(12505):    at com.example.maphelperlogin.Register$ProcessRegister.doInBackground(Register.java:1)
03-25 00:21:14.775: E/AndroidRuntime(12505):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
03-25 00:21:14.775: E/AndroidRuntime(12505):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
03-25 00:21:14.775: E/AndroidRuntime(12505):    ... 4 more
03-25 00:21:23.175: I/Choreographer(12505): Skipped 502 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-25 00:21:23.725: E/WindowManager(12505): Activity com.example.maphelperlogin.Register has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{42e12d30 V.E..... R......D 0,0-684,192} that was originally added here
03-25 00:21:23.725: E/WindowManager(12505): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.maphelperlogin.Register has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{42e12d30 V.E..... R......D 0,0-684,192} that was originally added here
03-25 00:21:23.725: E/WindowManager(12505):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:452)
03-25 00:21:23.725: E/WindowManager(12505):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:258)
03-25 00:21:23.725: E/WindowManager(12505):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:73)
03-25 00:21:23.725: E/WindowManager(12505):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:287) 03-25 00:21:23.725: E/WindowManager(12505):     at com.example.maphelperlogin.Register$ProcessRegister.onPreExecute(Register.java:119)
03-25 00:21:23.725: E/WindowManager(12505):     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
03-25 00:21:23.725: E/WindowManager(12505):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
03-25 00:21:23.725: E/WindowManager(12505):     at com.example.maphelperlogin.Register$2.onClick(Register.java:91)
03-25 00:21:23.725: E/WindowManager(12505):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
03-25 00:21:23.725: E/WindowManager(12505):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
03-25 00:21:23.725: E/WindowManager(12505):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
03-25 00:21:23.725: E/WindowManager(12505):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-25 00:21:23.725: E/WindowManager(12505):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 03-25 00:21:23.725: E/WindowManager(12505):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
03-25 00:21:23.725: E/WindowManager(12505):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-25 00:21:23.725: E/WindowManager(12505):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-25 00:21:23.725: E/WindowManager(12505):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
03-25 00:21:23.725: E/WindowManager(12505):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
03-25 00:21:23.725: E/WindowManager(12505):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the parser class:

```
public class JSONParser {
    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                //If I add the following therror gets removed but I receive the message "missing required sets"
               //httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");                
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

and here is the register class that extends the asynctask:

```
class ProcessRegister extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        JSONObject json;

         @Override
         protected void onPreExecute() {
             super.onPreExecute();
             pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Register.this);
             pDialog.setMessage("Registering new user..");
             pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
             pDialog.setCancelable(true);
             pDialog.show();
         }



        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int success;

            String firstname= inputFirstName.getText().toString();
            String lastname= inputLastName.getText().toString();
            String username= inputUsername.getText().toString();
            String email= inputEmail.getText().toString();
            String pass= inputPassword.getText().toString();

            // Building Parameters
            List <NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("firstname", firstname));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lastname", lastname));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pass));

            for(int i=0;i<params.size();i++){
                System.out.println("here: "+params.get(i).toString());

            }

            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create product url accepts POST method
            json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_register_user,"POST", params);

            //Log.d("Create Response 1", json.toString());

            try{
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            //Log.d("Create Response 2", json.toString());
            String successu = success == 1 ? "success" : null;

                return successu;

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String resp) {
            // dismiss the dialog once done
            // check log cat fro response
            if(resp != null){
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    //Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

                    // successfully created user
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                    // closing this screen
                    finish();
                    // failed to create user

            }else{

                    try {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unsuccessful registration due to "+json.getString("message").toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                    pDialog.dismiss();        
        }
    }
```

I have tried to print or echo the params element that I am sending in the processregister class and it is displayed in html format in the logcat. Thus, it it not caught by the first if statement in the php file. In fact, I think it is a php file error caused by a wrong JSON parsing. I have seen several questions on this same error but no luck. Can someone please assist me in solving my issue. Thank you very much.

EDIT:
The problem was a returned PHP error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly NEVER post Android logcat output here on StackOverflow in a quoted text format - it has just taken me a long time to format that into a readable code block and until I did, the problem with the `<br` element wasn't visible.

Secondly, what you're getting from the server isn't pure JSON by the look of it.

The exception...

```
E/JSON Parser(12505): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

...is showing  it is `<br` which is causing the problem. This is an HTML element which suggests your server is returning JSON wrapped in HTML.

**EDIT:** Thirdly, the reason the logcat is showing WindowLeaked exceptions is this in the `doInBackground(...)` method of your `AsyncTask`...

```
        String firstname= inputFirstName.getText().toString();
        String lastname= inputLastName.getText().toString();
        String username= inputUsername.getText().toString();
        String email= inputEmail.getText().toString();
        String pass= inputPassword.getText().toString();
```

...don't try to access any UI elements in the `doInBackground(...)` method. It runs on a separate thread and can't access the UI elements on the main (UI) thread.

Comment: I have moved the lines outside of the class and made them golbal variables. Problem is it is still giving me the same exception. I fixed that PHP error now it s working ! thank you so much.

Comment: @Orochi1992 : I suggest you start a new question about the WindowLeaked issue but glad I could help with the PHP problem.

Answer (score 1):

Some things you could try:

1. Make sure you're getting a response from the server. Start the debugger in eclipse and set a breakpoint at `json = sb.toString();`. If you're not getting a response, then you need to investigate your PHP.
2. If you're getting a response, then make sure you're receiving valid JSON. Copy and paste the response into [here](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/).

Comment: Thanks for the suick response it's returning html which I think is due to the php file. I can't fidn any error in the PHP too.